# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE/Failed to fetch node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to make a simple login/signup page but my fetch code is causing errors (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and TypeError: Failed to fetch). I tried console.log("can login") to see if the code would return something, confirming it works, however, neither function returns anything. I'm new, so please have mercy on me

```
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))    
    let {username, password} = req.body;
    let err = validate.username(username);
    if(err) throw err;
    err = validate.password(password);
    if(err) throw err;
        db.collection("users").find({username: username}), function(err, username){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            } if(username){
                console.log(username);
                console.log("Username in use!");
            } else {
            console.log("Not in use!");
            db.collection("users").insertOne({ "username": username.value, "password": password.value });
            }  
        }
    }); 

    router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))    
        let {username, email, password} = req.body;
        db.collection("users").find({username: username, password: password}), function(err, results){
            if(err){
            throw err;
            } if(results.length > 0){
            console.log("Can login");
            } else {
            throw("Username and/or Password is incorrect!");
            }
        }
    }); 


<script>
        function register() {
            let data = { 
                username: document.querySelector("#user").value,
                password: document.querySelector("#pass").value,
            }
        
        

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

            fetch("/api/register", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            
            }).then((res) => {
                console.log(res.json());
            });        
        }
        function login() {
            let data = { 
                username: document.querySelector("#userlogin").value,
                password: document.querySelector("#passlogin").value,
            }

        fetch("/api/login", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            
            }).then((res) => {
                console.log(res.json());
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Register:</h1>
   
    <input autocomplete="username" id = "user" placeholder="username">
    <input autocomplete="current-password" id = "pass" type = "password "placeholder="password">
    <button onclick="register()">Register</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input autocomplete="username" id = "userlogin" placeholder="username">
    <input autocomplete="current-password" id = "passlogin" type = "password" placeholder="password">
    <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
 
</body>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not sending any response in your `login`-handler, thus you get an empty response error on the client-side. Change it to something like:

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))    
        let {username, email, password} = req.body;
        db.collection("users").find({username: username, password: password}), function(err, results){
            if(err){
               res.status(500).json({errorMsg: err.message});
            } else if(results.length > 0){
               res.json({ // send whatever you need here });
            } else {
               res.status(401).json({errorMsg: "wrong user/password"});
            }
        }
    });
```

In your client-code you should also handle the case of an error:

```
fetch("/api/login", { ... })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.json());
            }).catch(err) => {
              // handle error here
            })
```